# UIStatusBar Transition Animation -- Change Alpha Only

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uistatusbar

I am trying to have the UIStatusBar fade out during a transition, and fade back in on completion. (This is purely stylistic - I have a transition that comes from the top and to me at least, going under the UIStatusBar is jarring looking)

Is there a way to not remove the UIStatusBar but just make the whole view.layer.alpha = 0.0?

iOS9.2 & Swift2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't think its possible Apple seems to be making a push to view controller based status bar control and depreciating all of the api to manually change the status bar state. I really hope in the next WWDC they will introduce replacements for these. I am facing the same problem in my application due to custom transitions that need to change status bar color/style.

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isProximitySensingEnabled) BOOL proximitySensingEnabled NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 3_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED; // default is NO. see UIDevice for replacement
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 3_2) __TVOS_PROHIBITED; // use -setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:

// Explicit setting of the status bar orientation is more limited in iOS 6.0 and later.
@property(readwrite, nonatomic) UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 9_0, "Explicit setting of the status bar orientation is more limited in iOS 6.0 and later") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
- (void)setStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation animated:(BOOL)animated NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 9_0, "Explicit setting of the status bar orientation is more limited in iOS 6.0 and later") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;

// Setting the statusBarStyle does nothing if your application is using the default UIViewController-based status bar system.
@property(readwrite, nonatomic) UIStatusBarStyle statusBarStyle NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 9_0, "Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
- (void)setStatusBarStyle:(UIStatusBarStyle)statusBarStyle animated:(BOOL)animated NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 9_0, "Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;

// Setting statusBarHidden does nothing if your application is using the default UIViewController-based status bar system.
@property(readwrite, nonatomic,getter=isStatusBarHidden) BOOL statusBarHidden NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 9_0, "Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_2, 9_0, "Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;

- (BOOL)setKeepAliveTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout handler:(void(^ __nullable)(void))keepAliveHandler NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_0, 9_0, "Please use UIRemoteNotificationTypeVoIP remote notifications for VoIP applications") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
- (void)clearKeepAliveTimeout NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_0, 9_0, "Please use UIRemoteNotificationTypeVoIP remote notifications for VoIP applications") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

Comment: I think I will make this as the answer. Quick question though: view.animatewithduration, you can hide the status bar with animation using self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate and a variable to set false to true. I found running that by itself works, but if you try to chain a second block, it immediately fails the first. Is there an easy way to prevent this other than what I am about to doing, that being adding an invisible view to manipulate?